# make 4 squares in assembly,and click with mouse to fill one of them

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm a beginner in assembly 8086, and i wrote this code, that makes four squares,and when I select one of the squares with mouse to fill,**the other** square begins to fill,(for example,when i click the **first** square the **second** square begins to fill while i wanted the first square to fill),i don't know why this happens ,please help me.

```
push_all macro
        push cx              ;push all macros
        push dx 
endm

pop_all macro           ;pop all macros
        pop dx
        pop cx
endm 

FILL    MACRO ROW_START,COL_START,ROW_END,COL_END 

        LOCAL START,AGAIN
        push_all
        MOV   DX,ROW_START
START:  MOV   CX,COL_START
AGAIN:  MOV   AH,0CH
        MOV   AL,02
        INT   10H
        INC   CX
        CMP   CX,COL_END
        JNE   AGAIN
        INC   DX
        CMP   DX,ROW_END
        JNE   START
        pop_all
ENDM


SQUARE MACRO CLMN
LOCAL U
LOCAL U1
LOCAL U2
LOCAL U3     

;PUSH_ALL




MOV CX,CLMN
MOV DX,10
U:
MOV AH,0CH
MOV AL,02
INT 10H
inc CX
CMP CX,CLMN+10
JNZ U  



MOV CX,CLMN
MOV DX,10
U1:
MOV AH,0CH
MOV AL,02
INT 10H
inc dX
CMP dX,20
JNZ U1  



MOV CX,CLMN
MOV DX,20
U2:
MOV AH,0CH
MOV AL,02
INT 10H
inc CX
CMP CX,CLMN+10
JNZ U2 



MOV CX,CLMN+10
MOV DX,20
U3:
MOV AH,0CH
MOV AL,02
INT 10H
DEC DX
CMP DX,9
JNZ U3

;POP_ALL

ENDM 

initmouse macro
        mov ax,0
        int 33h
endm 

getmouse macro 

LOCAL L
LOCAL L1
LOCAL L2
LOCAL L3
LOCAL L4
LOCAL M
LOCAL M1
LOCAL M2
LOCAL M3
LOCAL M4
LOCAL M5
LOCAL M6
LOCAL M7

push_all

      ;push all registers
L:
mov ax,1    ;show mouse
int 33h

mov ax,3    ;get pose
int 33h
cmp bx,1
jne L  

CMP CX,20
JB L1  
JMP X
L1:
FILL 10,10,20,20

JMP EN

X:
CMP CX,35
JB L2
JMP XX
L2:
FILL 10,25,20,35

JMP EN


XX:
CMP CX,50
Jb L3
JMP XXX
L3:
FILL 10,40,20,50

JMP EN

XXX:
CMP CX,65 
JB L4
L4:
FILL 10,55,20,65

JMP EN


pop_all
en:

ENDM

wait_for_key macro

INITMOUSE 
GETMOUSE
ENDM    




.data           

.CODE  

MAIN PROC FAR

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax 

MOV AH,00
MOV AL,13H
INT 10H

SQUARE 10
SQUARE 25
SQUARE 40
SQUARE 55    
wait_for_key 

END MAIN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just corrected it, 
you`ve gotta correct the get_mouse coordinates(CX as Column) as user is clicking on it.

```
CMP CX,25h
JB L1

X:
CMP CX,45h

XX:
CMP CX,65h

XXX:
CMP CX,85h
```